# bar attributes at once d3

Tags: d3.js, attributes, bar-chart

It's more conceptual issue rather than technical. So, I took relevant part only. 
I'm making a bar chart using rect in d3. It works well but I'd like to update the code below so that the last four lines can be simplified into one.

```
    g.selectAll(".bars")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bars")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return xScale(d.x); })
        .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.y); });
```

I tried by making a var containing bar attributes and getting this when selecting rect.

```
var barAttrs = { 
    x: function(d, i) { return xScale(d.x); },
    width: xScale.bandwidth(),
    y: function(d) {return yScale(d.y); },
    height: function(d) { return height - yScale(d.y); }
}

    g.selectAll(".bars")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bars")
        .attr(barAttrs);
```

It should work in theory, however, it doesn't work. Do you happen to know what is missing?

Thanks,

Comment: depends on the version of d3 you use, for d3v5 use https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi

Comment: Thanks for the referring. It helped a lot!